# Where To find online PHP/CSS Syntax Generator?

Tags: php, css, syntax, code-generation

i would like to learn how to make PHP/CSS syntax generator. i assume this going to be fun and all. Is there any open source PHP/CSS syntax generator ?

Or at least, where the best syntax generator available in internet based on your experience ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean syntax highlighting?

Syntax generation in PHP is going to be pretty hard as it is a scripting language and you decide on what you write.. I.E. it doesn't follow strict rules...

CSS on the other hand consists of names elements which apply to html elements which all have the same basic rules (e.g. color, width, height ...).

There are a number of CSS generators out there both web based and pc/mac/linux based... It depends what you want.

If you mean syntax highlighting, well thats's different altogether... There are a number of open source implementations of syntax highlighting...

E.g. http://qbnz.com/highlighter/

Comment: @jd : Thanks for the replay. no it's not highlight, but code-generation. the admin has kind enough to edit my wrong tags.

yes, i understand now the different problem of PHP and CSS based on their coding rules. thanks. I need to see /read code of similar project with what i want to create. So, at least, i know where to go when coding it.

Comment: @justjoe Sorry if this sounds rude but you're just not making much sense.

Comment: @brian : yeah, maybe, your're right. i'm not really good with English Grammar. Basicly, i seek an example of site who run php/css generator. so i can study how their work

Answer (score 1):

so x goes in and a CSS comes out; what's X?

Comment: @roy : what ? user input or something like that ?

Comment: he's asking what you're generating the CSS from. Knowing what you plan on building the CSS and PHP from will help get an answer to better solve the problem you're having (are you making some kind of templates? Trying to build them from some kind of spec? What?)

Comment: @carson myers :  i plan to make it as feature, simple part of my personal project. it's work by reading a css file then show it in form. it also work on reverse or something like that.